# mysqli_real_escape_string makes program useless

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, emoticons

The code below takes a  string protects its using `mysqli_real_escape_string`.
but not geting expected output working fine without the `mysqli_real_escape_string` but need that for protection.

```
  $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['str']);
    /*
      get each word in the sentence using for-loop then 
    */
    switch($eachword){
        case ':)': $eachword = '<img src="smile.gif">';
        break; 
    /*
      and so forth and so on
    */
    }


    $newstr .= $eachword;
    //for-loop ends


**mysqli_query($con,"insert into tbl(comment)VALUES($newstr)");**
```

e.g

- input : $str = "here i am :) fine";
- expected output : `$newstr="here i am <img src="smile.gif"> fine";`
- curernt output : `$newstr="here i am :) fine";`

**UPDATE**

NOW everything works fine. Thanks to supporters.

Comment: Why do you need it for protection?

Comment: Instead of string escaping, have you tried parameterizing the query? Or is there even a query involved?

Comment: I think @Quentin figured it out. You need htmlspecialchars. Notice the "mysqli" part of `mysqli_real_escape_string`. That's for writing database queries.

Comment: to be honest, why are you looping each word? just use str_replace for replacing emoticons with markup... much much much quicker!

Comment: yes i do need a query updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED

Note that you must be already connected to a database, for `mysqli_real_escape_string` to work, because it takes into consideration, the default character set of your selected database. Are you connecting to a database before using it?

And in your question, I don't even see a query. There will be no advantage in using `mysqli_real_escape_string` unless you're going to insert the passed string into a database.

Now I see that you're replacing smileys with  tag, then you're inserting it into a database. However, if I were you, I would do the following :

```
function ParseSmiley($str)
{
    $smileys = array(
        ':)' => "<img src='smile.gif' />" //Put all your smileys in this array
    );

    $parsed_string = strtr($str, $smileys);
    return $parsed_string;
}
```

When you're inserting your content into database, do not convert it into  tags. Instead, when you display it, use the function `ParseSmiley()`

```
$parsed_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['str']);

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbl (comment) VALUES ($parsed_string)");
```

Then when you want to display the content, let's say the string is in `$content`, display it like this :

`echo ParseSmiley($content);`

Comment: that means you insert into db as it is and output as '<img>' elements on displaying?

Comment: @user3187838 Yes, exactly. That way, you do not have to worry about the quotes in <img> tags being removed.

Answer (score 4):

You are running  `mysqli_real_escape_string` over some data immediately before … not using at all in your code sample. So it doesn't make any sense.

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` **immediately** before inserting the variable into a string of SQL and nowhere else. (Better yet, use prepared queries and bound arguments).

If you are trying to defend against XSS, then use `htmlspecialchars` **immediately** before inserting a variable into a string of HTML.

Don't use either before comparing user input to some text.

Comment: whats `XSS` ? ia m defending user to enter some `html` stuffs it can be done using `htmlentites` but also have to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` before inserting it.

Comment: if i use `mysqli_real_escape_string` just before inserting into db. the '<img>' elements i.e emoticons apear as `html codes` not images!!

Comment: As mentioned previously, nothing in your question is vulnerable to any kind of attack. If you want to insert stuff into a database, then you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` **immediately** before you put it in the SQL string. Not at the top of your script. **immediately** before you put it in the SQL.

Comment: "if i use mysqli_real_escape_string just before inserting into db. the '`<img>`' elements i.e emoticons apear as html codes not images!!" — Then you need to look at what you get out of the database and what you do with that, not at what you put into it.

Comment: "Then you need to look at what you get out of the database and what you do with that, not at what you put into it."  -- what can i do? @quentin